# Query different table when column exist

Tags: mysql, sql

Database: MySql 5.5.3

I have a `type` column in table `topic`, if the `type` is 'E' which means there is an entry exist in 'Event' Table and it should query "TOPIC_HAS_EVENT" table to get few more colums from the EVENT Table. In the same way if Type is 'P' which means there is an entry exist in 'Poll Table' and it should query "TOPIC_HAS_POLL" table to get few columns from POLL Table. If the type is null then it should query as usual to get all the rows and their comments from the comment table.

The end results should have all the topics rows of all types ('E','P', NULL) and their specific columns from other table. If that can accomplish easily then i need to add few more columns as mentioned below

### More complex

If  type='E' have some rows, it should get some more rows such as user information from EVENT_HAS_USER table.

## Relationship

```
Each Topic has Many Comments
Each Topic has One Event
Each Topic has One Poll

EVENT ManyTOMany User
```

## Query so far created. I still need to add 'type' column. Please help me with it.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
        T.TOPIC_GUID, COUNT(*) TOTAL_COMMENTS
    FROM
        CIRCLE C, CIRCLE_HAS_USER CHU, CIRCLE_HAS_TOPIC CHT, TOPIC T
    LEFT JOIN TOPIC_COMMENT TC ON T.TOPIC_GUID = TC.TOPIC_GUID
    WHERE
        CHT.CIRCLE_GUID = C.CIRCLE_GUID
            AND T.TOPIC_GUID < 400000 -- ?
            AND CHT.TOPIC_GUID = T.TOPIC_GUID
            AND CHU.CIRCLE_GUID = C.CIRCLE_GUID
            AND CHU.USER_GUID = 1
            AND CHU.STATUS = 'A'
    GROUP BY T.TOPIC_GUID
    ORDER BY T.LAST_UPDATED_TIMESTAMP DESC
    LIMIT 10
```

Comment: This is only a comment on your query.  First, you don't need `DISTINCT` when you use `GROUP BY`.  Second, you should use proper join syntax in the `FROM` clause -- `INNER JOIN`, `LEFT OUTER JOIN`, etc. with an `ON` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select (case when type = 'type1' then (select field from table1) else (select field from table2) end) as a from table;
```